# Could one swap the direction of >> and << overloads to define them as class members?

Tags: c++, operators, stream-processing

Some operators cannot be overloaded as class members. One such example are the bitwise shift operators used for streams [see here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421729). The reason for that (as far as I understand it) seems to be that the left hand site operand is the one you define the behaviour for and you cannot define behaviour for the built-in streams. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I think it would be useful to define those overloads as class members, because they likely need to access private data. Sure, there's `friend`, but that seems to be more of a workaround.

Now this is more of a hypothetical question, but **why not swap the meaning of `>>` and `<<`** then?

```
obj >> std::cout;
obj << std::cin;
```

This way, the whole operation happens from the point of view of the object, not the stream. The overload can be made as a member function, because the object is the left hand operand. **Would that be possible?**

I guess there are a lot of things this would break, like readability for starters as everybody is used to the other way. **What other things would this break?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator overloads in C++ are [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), nothing more. Your example will work fine: however, consider two things. First, how do people expect stream operators (technically bitshift operators) to function? They expect them to be able to be *chained*: the second idea to consider is how does your example work with chaining?

Given this code:

```
std::cout << obj1 << obj2 << std::endl;
```

What is really going on is this, once you remove the syntactic sugar:

```
std::cout.operator<<(obj1).operator<<(obj2).operator<<(std::endl);
```

Remember, `operator<<()` returns a reference to `*this` by convention (true in the standard library, and a good idea in general to allow chaining operators this way). That means that all of those calls are invoked on `std::cout`, the first object referenced in that statement.

Now consider your example:

```
obj >> std::cout;
```

If you extend this to chain multiple objects, you might get this:

```
obj1 >> obj2 >> std::cout;
```

Which would look like this if converted to proper function calls:

```
obj1.operator>>(obj2).operator>>(std::cout);
```

What this means is yes, you can reverse the order, but it will break down and not behave the way C++ programmers expect once you chain multiple functions together.

Comment: Espectially since for `obj1.operator>>(obj2)...` your class needs a class member operator >> for every single other type that can ever exist, ever.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Or a template one.

Answer (score 3):

Swapping the direction of the I/O operators to move the operands to the left-hand side would be technically possible, but the "chaining" which is often used for I/O streaming would be at least cumbersome. Instead of

```
std::cout << "The result is " << result << endl;
```

you would have to write either

```
"The result is " >> std::cout;
result >> std::cout;
std::endl >> std::cout;
```

or

```
std::endl >> (result >> ("The result is " >> std::count));
```

which feels unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the problems already cited (which mostly boil down to lack of chaining), you have another fundamental problem here. Consider what happens if you try to work with a type that's built into the compiler:

```
int x;

x << std::cin;
```

Lacking a free function overloaded to do the job, this would be trying to do `x.operator<<(std::cin);`. Since `x` is of type `int`, it doesn't and can't contain any overloaded operators.

So, for all the built-in types, you'd *still* have to implement the overload as a free function like you do now, or else build wrappers like Java's `Integer` just to handle these overloads. Neither seems (at least to me) to provide any meaningful improvement over the current situation.

Comment: This is a good point because it addresses the "overload in a **method**" (member of a class) aspect of the question, because not everything is a class.